# Resolve Thymeleaf templates in WEB-INF

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc, thymeleaf

I want to send email using thymeleaf to render the email message. Here is my configuration in Spring 4 **applicationContext.xml**:

```
<bean id="thymeleafMailEngine" class="org.thymeleaf.TemplateEngine">
    <property name="templateResolver" ref="thymeleafMailResolver" />
</bean>
<bean id="thymeleafMailResolver" class="org.thymeleaf.templateresolver.FileTemplateResolver">
    <property name="templateMode" value="XHTML" />
    <property name="prefix" value="src/main/webapp/WEB-INF/templates/" />
    <property name="characterEncoding" value="UTF-8" />
    <property name="cacheable" value="false"/>
</bean>
<bean id="websiteMailSender" class="com.mycompany.service.MailSenderWithAttachmentSupport">
    <property name="thymeleafEngine" ref="thymeleafMailEngine" />
    <property name="thymeleafResolver" ref="thymeleafMailResolver" />
</bean>
```

To send my email, I use:

```
        MimeMessage msg=mailSender.createMimeMessage();
        try {
            MimeMessageHelper helper = new MimeMessageHelper(msg, true, "UTF-8");
            //...
            final Context ctx = new Context();
            ctx.setVariables(model); //model is a Map<String,Object>
            helper.setText(thymeleafEngine.process(template, ctx)); //line 89
        } catch(MessagingException me) {
            log.error("Cannot send email message");
        }
```

It generates this Exception:

> org.thymeleaf.exceptions.TemplateInputException: Error resolving
>   template "my_template.html", template might not exist or might not be
>   accessible by any of the configured Template Resolvers    at
>   org.thymeleaf.TemplateRepository.getTemplate(TemplateRepository.java:246)
>     at org.thymeleaf.TemplateEngine.process(TemplateEngine.java:1104)   at
>   org.thymeleaf.TemplateEngine.process(TemplateEngine.java:1060)    at
>   org.thymeleaf.TemplateEngine.process(TemplateEngine.java:1011)    at
>   org.thymeleaf.TemplateEngine.process(TemplateEngine.java:924)     at
>   org.thymeleaf.TemplateEngine.process(TemplateEngine.java:898)     at
>   com.mycompany.service.MailSenderWithAttachmentSupport.send(MailSenderWithAttachmentSupport.java:89)

Comment: You are using the wrong template resolver. Use the servlet context one...

Comment: But I wont provide HTTP request/response, it is not logical

Comment: It has nothing to do what you are returning it has to do what is used for the lookup. Else move them to somewhere else and use the `ClassPathTemplateResolver` instead.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I just found a solution:

```
<bean id="thymeleafMailResolver" class="org.thymeleaf.spring4.templateresolver.SpringResourceTemplateResolver">
    <property name="templateMode" value="XHTML" />
    <property name="prefix" value="/WEB-INF/templates/" />
    <property name="characterEncoding" value="UTF-8" />
    <property name="cacheable" value="false"/>
</bean>
```